# Maven : should I put xml files in src/main/java folder?

Tags: maven

We've got many *beans.xml* and *struts.xml* files located in *src/main/java* folder. When `mvn package` is finished, I couldn't find those files in *WEB-INF/classes* folder.

Is it wrong to put xml files in *src/main/java*? Should I put them in *src/main/resources* instead? Or should I modify the pom.xml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard is to place them into src/main/resources  They will end up going into WEB-INF/classes when the war is packaged by maven.

Comment: Shoud I put only *.java files in src/main/java folder?

Comment: @user2432405 That is correct. The class files generated after compiling the java files in src/main/java are copied to WEB-INF/classes  Therefore non-source files will just be ignored.

Comment: @user2432405 hope that helps - feel free to mark the answer correct :)

Comment: Here's another way : <build> <resources><resource><directory>src/main/java</directory><excludes><exclude>**/*.java</exclude></excludes></resource><resource><directory>src/main/resources</directory></resource></resources></build>

Comment: @kharyam - I think you meant to say WEB-INF/classes when the war is packaged by maven? WEB-INF folder doesn't normally exist in a jar :)